# How are some applications made in several programming languages?

Tags: c++

It's been always a question for me how some (web, desktop) applications are made in couple of programming languages. For example, I hear (or read) that some apps such as firefox, photoshop or even amazon.com (logical codes of course) are written in C++ or that blah-blah app core is C++. To get to the point,  I wonder how a programmer(s) can integrate some programming languages or modules written in those to build an application in one piece? What exactly is the idea?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The basic idea is `gcc -o prog *.o`.

Comment: You build your communications interface between each module, then create bindings for it. There's a billion different ways to do it.

Comment: if you will name a couple of specific situations we can help, this question is way too generic, by the way many languages offers bindings or technologies to "connect" different languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might make sense to build different parts of an application in different technologies or languages. Some of the reasons might be:

- Performance requirements in a specific component; and therefore using a low-level language, when other components benefit more from a high-level language, allowing better developer productivity.
- "Best tool for the job" - the technology stack for presenting forms might not be good for crunching numbers.
- Migrating legacy apps - if you have a large codebase you need to migrate, it could make sense to migrate small parts instead of doing one big bang integration (those tend to fail).

If you are using two different languages that can run in the same runtime environment, the combination can be trivial. For example a .NET application that leverages both a C# and an F# assembly - or a C application with parts assembly code linked in.

However, for large applications today, the most common case is to have software components connected by services or message bus technologies; moving data and events from one component to another. Out-of-process communication can also be as simple as two components sharing a database or a file.

Comment: the question is "how" not "why" ...

Comment: The last 2 paragraphs addresses the "how".

Comment: you should drive a car from the trunk because it's the latest piece of it ...

Comment: @axis many cars have their engines in the trunk, it's done wonders for safety.

Comment: I would imagine most people riding a car from the trunk have been beaten, clubbed over the head and stuffed there. Not safe.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the how:

Ultimately, all compiled languages and scripting languages must be converted to a given machine's native machine code in order to be executed.

Compiler programming languages typically pass through several stages of conversion on their journey from source code to executable binaries - and one step on that road is binary libraries.

Now, if there's a standardised ABI (application binary interface) at such a level that standardises how a function call is made (parameters are passed, stack behaviour etc) then it would be possible to compile a diverse set of languages to converge on this ABI, and have the linker link them to produce an executable binary that is formed from what was originally a mix of diverse languages.

However, you can't just choose a diverse set of languages on a given platform.  To support this scheme, there needs to be a front end compiler that converges on this common back-end.

Scripting languages may also have so called 'bindings' to compiled languages, allowing them to be integrated in this same way, but at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and Photoshop have language bindings and have various runtime plugins that allow for the other languages to be used. These are in cases where extensibility and ease of development is better and allows for third party additions to be made.

Examples of this are:

- Lua bindings
- avascript bindings

The other example you have of Amazon and mixing of languages allows for distributed parts of their system to be written in a language that makes more sense in that particular area. Does the portion require a lot of speed? C++. Is there not a lot of logic but you incur a lot of call backs? NodeJS. There are a lot of problems that can be solved much easier and quicker in other languages than say sticking with just Java or C++.

Examples of how this is done:

- Message passing
- Databases
- RPC calls
- Remote API's

Comment: Thanks for the keywords.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in C++ you actually use programs written in different languages all the time, most likely.  Many of the functions in the Standard Library, like `operator new`, are implemented in Assmebly language, for speed.

@driis has already addressed two of the main ways in which components written in different languages can interract.  There's at least one more.

A single application can be made up of multiple components written in different languages.  For example, one program I work on has parts written in C++ and other parts written in Assembly.  I've worked on programs written in FORTRAN + C, even VB and C++ (Ick, not fun).

The idea is simple in concept.  All you need to do is make sure that one side knows where the other side's function is in memory, and that both sides using the same [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for the call.

The calling convention is an agreement on what order parameters and return addresses are pushed on to the stack, and other stuff like that.

Getting the address of the functions can be anywhere from a piece of cake to a nightmare.  In Windows C++ DLLs for example, it's easy.  Just link to the .lib and you good.  Getting VB to call a C or C++ function is a little trickier because VB doesn't know how to use these .lib files -- at least it didn't back in the day.  You had to do tricky stuff like what's posted [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/287584-calling-a-function-in-c-dll-from-vb60/).  You have to load the DLL directly and then assign a pointer to the address of the function.

Comment: Was that capitalisation a subtle hint that you call the Standard Library "STL"? Yikes!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  LOL,no.  That was the result of having large fingers, a small keyboard and being a generally, perhaps suprisingly poor typist.

Answer (score -3):

I will make my answer simple.

Consider a web application. It is typically written in HTML, Javascript, CSS and, say, PHP. There may also be SQL used within it.

I will assume that you do not need me to give code examples of this extremely common scenario, and instead leave you to ponder on how considering this scenario answers your question. :)